# can't establish table count from segued variable array holding struct instances

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, count, segue

Here is my code.
table 1

```
var types = ["American", "Burgers", "Deli", "Ethnic", "Italian", "Mexican", "Seafood", "Steakhouse"]

var restaurantsArray:[RestaurantModel] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let twotwenty = RestaurantModel(name: "220 Merrill", type: "American")
    let bistrojoe = RestaurantModel(name: "Bistro Joe's", type: "American")
    let dick = RestaurantModel(name: "Dick O' Dows", type: "Burgers")
    let rojo = RestaurantModel(name: "Roho Mexican Bistro", type: "Mexican")
    let Qdoba = RestaurantModel(name: "Qdoba", type: "Mexican")

    var restaurantsArray = [[twotwenty, bistrojoe],[dick],[],[],[],[rojo, Qdoba]]



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueone")
    {
        let index = self.tableView!.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
        if let nextrestaurant = index
        {
          var restaurantVC = (segue.destinationViewController as RestaurantTable)
            restaurantVC.restaurant = restaurantsArray[nextrestaurant.row]
        }

    }

}
```

and my second table controller.

```
var restaurant: RestaurantModel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return restaurant.count
```

I'm having a hard time establishing what I need to place in code to be able to use my restaurant variable in my second table controller to be used in the number of rows in section function.  ideas?

Comment: restaurant is RestaurantModel type, have you got count member inside the class? Can you print on the restaurant object in viewDidAppeare method in  RestaurantTable class?

Comment: i do not have a count member inside the class.  Im just looking to count the number of items in the appropriate array defined by the restaurant array.  the code also broke because it says it cannot index empty buffer

Comment: this is what i have overall https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jbd75kbvhh4hegk/AAACB8lJF3RStam8IQrjBIkba?dl=0

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do here. In the first table view you display array of strings (types) with 8 elements and it works fine. But when you click the row you trying to pass restaurantsArray[nextrestaurant.row] which is array of array (just 6 elements) to the object of type RestaurantModel. What are you trying to do?

Comment: the first controller is meant to display the type items.  and dependent upon the selection, i also have an index path.  that index path is pushed to my second controller where it tells which array in my restaurants array is meant to be displayed.

Comment: what i am trying to do is show the correct number of items in the second controller, of the restaurants array, because the type array is meant to go hand in hand with the index path of the numerous arrays in the restaurant array.

Comment: Remove keyword  var from restaurantsArray in viewDidLoad and replace it with: restaurantsArray = [twotwenty, bistrojoe, dick, rojo, Qdoba, dick, rojo, Qdoba]. It will sort the first error, your implementation with array of arrays won't work. After that implement cellForRowAtIndexPath in RestaurantTable class to get rid of the next one issue.

Comment: I guess some background would help.  I am going off this suggestion, but i need to use a struct model now because i need more information with each instance.  I assume the information would be comparable (as in, i would be able to copy this logic over for struct use)